# How can I assign variables directly from a text file?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ project, but I'm running into some issues. I have a text file:

```
5.123456789
9.987654321
6
```

I would like to have an assignments like this:

```
double firstLine = 5.123456789;
double secondLine = 9.987654321;
int thirdLine = 6;
```

How could I assign the values directly from the text file?

This is what I have so far:

```
string line = "";
ifstream infile;
infile.open("xinput.txt");
while(getline(infile,line))
    {
        //I suppose this is where I would have to insert my missing code,
        //but I am unsure how to proceed.
    }
infile.close();
```

Comment: And what problem(s) are you having with this code?

Comment: `double x = 0; infile >> x;` would read a `double` into `x`. Perhaps it's time for a good book?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you want, you want to know how to assign the value in your .txt to variables.

If it is, you would need something like that :

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("xinput.txt");

double firsLine;
double secondLine;
int thirdLine;

while (!infile.eof())
{
    getline(infile, firstLine, '\n');
    getline(infile, secondLine, '\n');
    getline(infile, thirdLine, '\n');
}
infile.close();
```